# how to avoid confirm form resubmission?

Tags: php, html, forms, submission

is there any way to avoid confirm form re submission? `The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action that you took to be repeated.Do you want to continue?` Using javascript Or jquery function any kind of example to avoid confirm form re submission?

```
function getComboB(sel) { 
var invoices=document.getElementById("invoices");
var input_val = document.getElementById("invoices").value; 
invoices.action = "searchinvoices.php?invoices="+input_val+"";
invoices.submit();
} 


<table width="371" border="2">
<form name="invoices" id="invoices">
<tr>
<td width="160"><font class="font2">&nbsp;Search By Invoice's Number:</font></td>
<td width="198"><input type="text" class="input_field" style="background:#FFF !important;" name="invoices" id="invoices" onchange="getComboB();" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: post your code please..

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811368/returning-to-that-page-might-cause-any-action-you-took-to-be-repeated-django

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a feature that the browser automatically implements as a security feature. This is not easily bypassed, because it's part of the browser software. My best two suggestions would be to redirect the user using a header (if you can use some PHP on the page):

```
header("Location: http://example.com");
```

Or to see if Chrome has a [flag](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2012/07/all-about-chrome-flags.html) for it. In other browsers, you may be out of luck. Cheers!