# ASPX Page Response.Redirect to MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to Response.Redirect in aspx that returns a view from MVC?

I have an login.aspx page that i need upon successful login to redirect to a view in ~/Views/Home/index.cshtml is this possible? I've tried to following but the url couldnt be resolved.

tried:

1. `Response.Redirect("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");`
2. `Response.Redirect("Home");`

The controller is "HomeController" and the view is "Index.cshtml" any help with how to call a controller and view or atleast just the url would help.

Comment: `Response.Redirect(url)` will send the user to wherever `url` is. It doesn't matter if the URL is to a resource on the same site, or on some other side, or to technology shown by a different view engine. As long as it's a valid URL, it'll go there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");` - that is of course presuming that you have a `HomeController` with an `Index` action that returns the view you're looking for (by convention it's going to be a view having the same name as the action, unless you specify otherwise).

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I redirect from `.aspx` to an MVC view:

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
Response.Redirect(page.GetRouteUrl("yourRouteNameOrDefault", 
    new { Controller="Home", Action="Index"}), false);
```

Keeps you from hard-coding in the actual path and instead uses your routing and also allows you to build in `routeParameters`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

assuming that this is in the same controller , if not:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

in the MVC framework you don't redirect to views directly , you redirect to Actions, then there me be some logic in there , and based on the logic from the Action it will choose a view and fill out a view model if necessary

Comment: OP is in a webforms page.

Comment: but they have all MVC libraries added to project

Comment: PageLoad is `void`... what is OP `return`ing?

Comment: ahhhh ... yea you're right.  You could make that work , but there are better answers here

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
Response.Redirect(page.GetRouteUrl("Default",
    new { Controller = "Nameofcontroller", Action = "Nameofaction" }), false);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.