# How to route URL from classic asp to MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing asp application which is running from a long time and many clients used to post the from Form Post or Ajax post with different technologies (e.g. .Php, .Asp, .Aspx). now we are planning to upgrade the asp application to MVC5. As URL’s are modified and existing URL’s are not available they are getting 404 error.

Can anyone know how to route the URL from asp to MVC. Below is my example

http://bbbbbb.com/test/test/mytest.asp

to

http://newsite.com/mycontoller/myaction

Comment: Are you changing the domain too?

Comment: No, we are using same domain

Comment: Can you refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672952/aspx-page-response-redirect-to-mvc-view

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but we use permanent redirection. Just replace the code in http://bbbbbb.com/test/test/mytest.asp with:

```
<%
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://newsite.com/mycontoller/myaction"
%>
```