# Linking to a MVC controller from ASP page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have inherited a asp project with all new projects being done in MVC.  I have a link on an asp page which I would like to route to a MVC action but can't seem to manage this.  This is what I have so far which doesn't work.

ASP page:

```
<div id="mainMenuAnalystics" class="panel pageLink" runat="server">
                    <div class="header">
                        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="IDoNotExist.aspx"                              
                            Text="Analytics"
                            runat="server"/><br class="floatClear" />
                   </div>                    
                </div>
```

In the routeConfig.cs file I added this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Analytics",
            url: "DestinyWireless.src/aspx/IDoNotExist.aspx",
            defaults:
            new
            {
                controller = "Areas/MVC/Controllers/ReportingController",
                action = "Index"
            });
```

So instead of going to IdoNotexist.aspx, I want to redirect to the Index method in Reporting controller which is located at Areas/MVC/Controllers/ReportingController.  Anyone know how to achieve this?

Of course it would be great if I could just add a @Url.action on the asp page itself but it seems asp does not support razor.

Folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use full url for redirection like so `NavigateUrl="http://yourdomain/AreaName/ControllerName/ActionName"`.

Comment: I have added my current folder structure to the question.  At the moment I'm unable to link directly to the Index method. Please can you suggest te url syntax i should use. I have tried: "http://localhost:41334/Areas/MVC/Controllers/Reporting/Index"

Comment: Do aspx project and mvc project reside in same solution?

Comment: yes they are in the same solution and same project

Comment: Then please have a look at [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672952/aspx-page-response-redirect-to-mvc-view)

Comment: Great it works, thanks!  For clarity in case anyone else is looking at this for an answer, I had to add in Global.asax: AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); And then the asp link looks like this:  <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/MVC/Reporting/Index"